# After having started a project and suddenly having found new competition, how do you convince yourself to keep going?

Tags: project-management, project-planning

I understand this is a subjective question but I want to see how others dealt with this issue:

How do you convince yourself and your teammates while trying to start a business or a project and suddenly faced with competition, whether due to lack of research or entirely new startups, that we should keep going?

What are some motivational techniques, considering this quite specific situation?

I'm trying to learn this in advance before getting burned.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Find faults in the competition's project, and know you can do better.  Competition is a good thing, not a bad thing, in this context.   Without it, your efforts very well may be slower and less innovative.

Comment: It's a great suggestion. But additionally, how do you keep your members focuses and convinced that we can do better? Especially when "the other guys" have already come out with a product and have VC funding?

Comment: Being the underdog can and should be motivating.  Develop your work culture around all of this.  If you have defeated vibe in your team, find the source and squash it.  Some people are not cut out for start up work like this...maybe they'd be happier working doing HR systems for MegaCorp Inc. :P

Comment: According to Paul Graham and many others (me including) - VC funding is not necessarily a good thing...

Answer (score 11):

Competition only tells you, that you are on the right track. Deliver a better product than they do.

Comment: More than that, if i would have some project that does not have a competition i would start worry. Competition is the best sign that you have a potential market.

Comment: Use the competition as a guide - see what they're doing right/wrong and what feedback they're receiving.  Everyone/Everywhere has competition - watch a Rocky movie and get moving forward

Answer (score 6):

This is an amazing opportunity. You have an array of benefits.

1. Compare your product to competition. See what you did wrong and they got right. See what you didn't think of. Evaluate why you made decisions and how it compares to your competitor.
2. Now you know that there is a niche for whatever you are doing. After all, if somebody else is doing it, that probably means the idea is worth something and there is a need for it.

All in all, I had that happen to me. I released a project and a day after I found (quite obvious) competitors. Domain names were better and shorter, they were in the market for longer, had more content. That was a bit discoraging, however I realized my product is better in small ways. I also fixed a lot of usability bugs that I saw in competitors. And I am beginning to get traction: top results in Google, constant visits, bigger market share. There is a long way to go, but some of that path is simply doing better than the other guy. Plus a little bit more.

it's all about optimism

Comment: Heh, the key to pulling through is getting to a release before finding out about competition. Once ou've already released something, it's easier to continue on as you've put in a lot of work in already.

Comment: to some degree, competition forces you to be at your best

Answer (score 5):

If there is no competition, then I would get really worried. Having no competition can only mean 2 things:

1. You had a brilliant new idea nobody else ever thought of
2. There is no market for your product

While option 1 could be true, it is very unlikely.

If there is no competition, you probably created a product without a market, and then you are in real trouble.

Comment: Well, there were 2 situations so far: 1. Quite a novel idea, backed by new research and a really great group of guys. 2. A niche that was not explored by many, yet still promising.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that what your doing is really worth doing.  Regardless of competition if you have a great idea or you know your subject are better than anyone else does then you will succeed.

But when faced with this you need to look at your business case.  This is where you use judgement and flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the competition and do what your potential clients want / need. Also competition clarified that there is good market in there and don't forget market is always big enough to support more then one providers.